# Azure PAM doesn't receive Privileged access requests from a ‎"Microsoft Graph data connect‎" Data Factory pipeline execution

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, etl

PAM does not receive "Privileged access requests" from an Azure Pipeline querying data to Microsoft Graph.

The Pipeline uses the Service Principal, defined as a Microsoft best practice, shows "Requesting Consent", but no request is shown in the PAM page.

Here are the status page showing "Requesting Consent", and the error after a long timeout.

[image: Error after timeout]

[image: Pipeline_status_showing_RequestingConsent]

Comment: Could you please let me know if the solution helped in :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68971523/azure-data-factory-pipeline-showing-requestingconsent-forever/68979062#68979062

Comment: Hi Ipsita: you guessed: it is the same bad problem :-(

Answer (score 1):

At last I found what was missing: it was a licensing requirement, but nothing warned me about this in PAM page. Simply nothing was listed in it.
If you like, here are the requirements nowadays.

Licensing requirements are now visible in follow up.

Have a nice day to everyone !
Julian

Comment: What are the licensing requirements here?

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed the license requirement link is not working.
So, here I am trying again :-)

[image: Licensing Requirement screenshot]

So, a bundle of two licenses is always required.
Also "greater" licenses and trial licenses are suitable for this job.

For example, in the Azure Tenant lab, I was able to make it run, using
"Office E3 trial" + "Enterprise Mobility and security E5 trial" (The latter was the missing one that caused "PAM desertification").
It worked even if the specs say: "Office E3 + Enterprise Mobility and security E3" (not really E5 like mine).
I also had a P2 trial, but I suppose it was not really useful for this task.

Have a nice day !
Julian