# Azure data factory pipeline showing RequestingConsent forever

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, office365-apps, azure-data-factory

I am unable to fix the "Requesting Consent" status for an azure Data Factory Pipeline querying some Office365 (Graph) simple data (i.e. smtp addresses and UPN of my colleagues).

Can you suggest me something to check ?

I am adding 2 pictures showing where "Graph Data Connect" is easily enabled, and the always empty PAM (Privileged Access Management) portal.

[New image: Graph Data Connect configurator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIuRF.png)

[New image: Empty PAM portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwXuG.png)

Answer (score 0):

As per the error we could see its a permission issue where you need to be Granted Permission before querying in Graph  to pass simple data (i.e. smtp addresses and UPN of my colleagues).

Here, are the steps how you can add permissions:

> 1. You have to create a API permissions service, you have to [Grant Permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/howto-configure-prerequisites-for-reporting-api#grant-permissions) for reporting API, must allow your app the appropriate
>    permissions based on the API you wish to access.
> 2. Next you could navigate to `API Permission` in the left column under the `Manage`.
> 3. Then you can click on `+Add Permission` as shown in bubbles in the Snip.
> 4. Please grant the permissions `Directory.ReadWrite.All` and `Users.ReadWrite.All`.

[image]

Comment: Hi Ipsita. Thak you for your hints. I tried to assign these additive permissions, but the pipeline still waits in "Requesting Consent" and nothing is listed in "Privileged access requests" page :-( 
Application log shows it signs-in correctly, but I still get no requests to approve :-(

Comment: Hi @Julian, Have you provided the Storage Blob Data Contributor Role.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal?tabs=current, please lemme know if it works.

Comment: Hi @IpsitaDash-MT. I checked your link. Yes, I already gave to my registered application not only the "Storage Blob Data Contributor" Role on the whole storage account, but also upgraded it to owner of the resource group. If I am not wrong, prior to assign Contributor role, the linked service to the blob data storage didn't pass the "test connection" check.
I suppose you meant this kind of procedure.
Unfortunately, this also dosen't fix the problem :-(

Answer (score 0):

At last I found what was missing: it was a licensing requirement, but nothing warned me about this in PAM page. Simply nothing was listed in it.
If you like, here are the requirements nowadays.

[image]

Have a nice day to everyone !
Julian

Comment: Thank you so much @Julian for the update as I was checking what else was missing but wasn't sure enough.

Comment: It depends from the error you get. Tell me the error, and I can try to help you.
I found another blocking "little" thing: Exchange Online "data location at rest" MUST BE the same of your azure resource, or you will get errors like "Graph unaccessible".
Hope this can help also